# How To Automatically make particles when a player Joins Using Commands On Minecraft Bedrock Edition

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am attempting to make a kit PVP on Minecraft and I'm trying to make particles when a player joins the server.

Comment: Interesting, a player join detection question for MCBE doesn't seem to exist here yet. It's also more interesting than in MCJava, because there the answer is just "use the scoreboard objective for that", but that doesn't exist in MCBE as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

## Join Detection

The way I know to detect a join is by looking for people at world spawn. Of course this means that when someone dies, it will give them particles too. The way to get around this could be to set a spawn point for each player specifically when they join in. That solution will mean that they only get particles when they first join the world. If it doesn’t matter if someone dies and gets it when they spawn, I recommend the first option.

## Particle Command

Play particles on the nearest player:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ /particle minecraft:campfire_tall_smoke_particle ~ ~ ~
```

## How to Set World Spawn?

Example setting world spawn to 0, 10, 0:

```
/setworldspawn 0 10 0
```

## How to Set Player Spawn?

Example setting nearest player’s individual spawn to 10, 20, 15:

```
/spawnpoint @p 10 20 15
```

Comment: The `/` is not allowed in the subcommand of `/execute`.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 not true. I have just tested it out in game and as I thought it works. Try running `/execute @p ~ ~ ~ /say hi`

Comment: Hm. Perhaps Bedrock is different from Java 1.12-. The traditional syntax is without the `/` and it is required to omit the `/` in JE 1.12-. But BE could have it as an alternate syntax.

Comment: Yep its been like that since it was added and either syntax is correct, just like how slashes are optional in command blocks. I assume they are required to be omitted in function packs though, just like the normal first slash.